# ResultSet.getTimeStamp(1) is not work in some systems

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the code `ResultSet.getTimeStamp(1)` in one servlet. Am using JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 6.

In my system its work fine.But in server which have same configuration `ResultSet.getTimestamp(1)` throws invalid column type. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message you get.

Comment: Which type does the column you use on the server have? Is it really the same as for your development system?

Comment: am executing  this query "select Current_Timestamp from dual" and ResultSet.getTimestamp(1) throws invalid column type

Answer (score 0):

Could be a jdbc driver problem. Make sure, that you have only the correct and latest drivers on your actual class path. [Here's an external forum entry where exactly that was the issue](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=102820&postcount=12).