# resultSet.getTimeStamp() is not working

Tags: java, odbc

Am using  jdk- 1.6,
                         os-  redhat 5,
                         driver- class12.jar,(jar along with jdk lib)
                         db-Oracle 10g

for resultset.getTimestamp("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") it throws invalid column type exception

```
 public Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp timeStamp = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                timeStamp = rs.getTimestamp("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            }

        } catch(Exception e){}
        return timeStamp;
    }
```

In some system its works fine ,in server only it throws following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.
throwSqlException(DBError.java:189)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:231)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:294)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getTimestampValue(OracleStatement.java:4627)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.
```

Any body help mee....

Comment: possible duplicate of [ResultSet.getTimeStamp(1) is not work in some systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858507/resultset-gettimestamp1-is-not-work-in-some-systems)

Answer (score 2):

Your JDBC driver is really, REALLY old (like 10 years old).

The first thing you should try is using a current driver (ojdbc6.jar).

**Edit:** Here's a [discussion on the oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=354702) - it's definitely a driver bug fixed in Version 11.1.0.6.0 of the driver

Comment: @user735936: I can only repeat myself: try using a current JDBC driver.

Comment: @user735936: class12.jar is for Java 1.2 and 1.3, ojdbc14.jar is for Java 1.4, so they're both quite old and not ideal for a Java 6 app. I suspect that DaveHowes is correct about the cause of your specific problem, but that is still a problem in the driver that might be fixed by a later version.

Comment: but in jdk lib class12.jar is added .. so it defaultly takes that one... if i add ojdbc14,jar no affect

Comment: @user735936: here's a very relevant discussion on the oracle forums: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=354702 It's definitely a driver bug that was fixed in version 11.1.0.6.0 of the driver - not sure how to find out what version your JARs are though.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do

```
     String timeStamp = null;
     try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            timeStamp = rs.getString("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        }

    } catch(Exception e){}
```

I have a feeling that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in Oracle returns a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type that isn't mapped correctly in the JDBC driver. You may have to get it as a string and parse it manually.

As far as it working on some machines and not others, this *might* be due to the Timezones on the oracle installation and the timezones of the JVM being set up differently.

Comment: Thank you very much...  Please tell me how to change timezone in jvm because am using getTimestamp in all my codes more than 70 times

Comment: getTimestamp() will work when you use it against DATE or TIMESTAMP columns - I think your problem is due to the specific call that you make here - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type. If the other 69 times you use getTimestamp() are against DATE or TIMESTAMP columns then you don't have a problem - or not a big one anyway

Comment: you can set it using a start up JVM parameter -Duser.timezone=blah. I have to confess that I have never done this though.

Answer (score 0):

One note from the JavaDoc for `getTimeStamp(int columnIndex )` (and other methods): `@param columnIndex the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...`, it's not 0-based, so `getTimeStamp(1)` would return the first column. Is that what you want? Or might your timestamp column be the second in the resultset?

Edit: I don't see you using `getTimestamp(1)` in your code.

Comment: Yes, finally saw that. The question suggested otherwise.

Comment: AM USING resultset(columnlabel);